# execute mach-0 bundle executable i386

Tags: macos, mach-o

I have few files with the extension `.macho32` but not able to execute...

when i checked the type using file command it showed me

```
1169168835_559582_T.macho32: Mach-O bundle i386
```

any idea about this file type ? and how can i execute them.

Answer (score 2):

From [Mach-O specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html):

> The MH_BUNDLE file type is the type typically used by code that you load at runtime (typically called bundles or plug-ins). By convention, the file name extension for this format is .bundle.

bundle files are not the same thing as an executable mach-o binary.